# Get data from HTML and store into $(window).load()

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id = "userText"/>
   <button onclick="getData()">Send</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
  var inputUser;
  // I tried this and it didn't work either

  function getData(){
    inputUser = document.getElementById("userText").value;
    alert(inputUser);
  }

  $(window).load(
    function(){ * something * })
```

I can get data in function getData() but can't access that data into $(window).load(function()).

If I put `document.getElementById()` or try to use `inputUser` in * something * code. It's return nothing. I want use the text input from user in * something *.

So how can i do this? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: You should try using `$(document).load` while making sure `getData` is available in scope. Also when you do Window.load, the input field is not available and getData is not available too.

Comment: "_It's return nothing_" Nope, unless an error occur, it returns an empty string, that's something.

Comment: I tried init ```var inputUser``` outside getData function and it's didn't work too. *It's return nothing* is acutally return ```undefined```.

Answer (score 2):

The load event fires at the moment when the user has loaded the document.

At that point, the user hasn't typed anything into the form.

You can't get the text input in that function because **it doesn't exist yet**.

Comment: I agree with you at this point. So how can I use the text input from user without delete the $window.load() ?

Comment: Why do you want to keep `$window.load() `? It sounds like a solution looking for a problem rather than the other way around. Solve your actual problem instead.

Comment: I don't know why but when i delete $window.load(), my google map disappear

Comment: What Google Map? Maybe you should ask a new question about your actual problem with an [mcve].

Comment: Thank you so much! I asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048256/google-map-disappear-when-delete-window-load)

Answer (score 1):

You declared `var inputUser` inside `getData()`, therefore you can only access it inside `getData()` (it's called a scope).

Declare it outside (just above) with `var inputUser;`. Then, inside getData() just set it with `inputUser = ...` (without another `var`) and then you can access it from `$(window).load`.

Comment: I tried init var outside getData function and it's didn't work too.