# Google Map disappear when delete $(window).load()

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-left:25%">
  <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>      

  $(window).load(
    function(){

        var HoChiMinh = {lat: 10.7867246, lng: 106.6735853};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: HoChiMinh,
          zoom: 13,
        });

    });

</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY') }}"
        async defer></script>
```

I don't know what `$(window).load()` actually do here.

When I delete the line  `$(window).load()`, my Google Map didn't load. The screen return nothing, until I put `$(window).load()` back, it works again.

I need to delete `$(window).load()` for using some data from user input inside HTML code.

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

I still don't really understand what `$(window).load()` actually do here.

But I've just found one solution. When I put `&callback=initMap` in

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY') }}&callback=initMap"async defer></script>`

And define the function() to function initMap(). It works! Now my website can load the map without  `$(window).load()`.